# What is the order of points of a polygonz surface in postgis

Tags: postgis, 3d

I extracted points of polygonz surfaces using ST_DumpPoints. I need to generate grid points on these surfaces so, for this purpose I need to know order of points. Because I need to know which vertices are neighbour and which are not. I am using this formula to calculate coordinates of new points ;

Every piece has base vertex A0 (x0, y0, z0) and two neighbor vertices A1 and A2. Make base vectors

V1 = A1 - A0 V2 = A2 - A0 To make regular grid points inside this piece of plane,

P(u, v) = A0 + V1 * u + V2 * v where u and v are equally-spaced parameters

So what are the order of points that make polygonz surface?

Answer (score 1):

> (ST_DumpPoints(geom)).path

should give you the path to each point inside the geometry

**Edit**

As you can see in the doc:
http://postgis.net/docs/ST_DumpPoints.html

ST_DumpPoints returns a geometry_dump, which according to the doc :

http://postgis.net/docs/geometry_dump.html
is a

> geometry_dump is a compound data type consisting of a geometry object
>   referenced by the .geom field and path[] a 1-dimensional integer array

In the doc for ST_Dumppoints there is also an example showing the path output.

This path array is an ordinary PostgreSQL array which can be examined with PostgreSQL functions for arrays:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-array.html

So if you know that your polygon only have 1 ring (one boundary without holes) you can see what order each point has with :

```
(ST_DumpPoints(g.geom)).path[2]
```

path[1] will just be 1 for first ring.
But if your polygons have holes you cannot ignore that first position in the array.

Comment: what is the path could you explain more? @Nicklas Avén